# Replacing the default File copy Dialog

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry

i'm trying to replace the default file copy dialog with my own program, which I want to create with vb.net.

[image: File copy Dialog in Windows]

**My problem:**
Where can I enter my application path to start automatically (and parse arguments/paths) when the user copies and/or pastes files?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to monitor a file path I would suggest using FileSystemWatcher Class. This will monitor a folder for any files that are copied and pasted to the location. There is a great example at the below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This looks good, but this would require my program to run at startup in the background and wait for a OnChanged event. Is this a wise thing to do?

Comment: The way I see it is that you have 2 options: the file watcher or a command line line that runs every X min's to check and see if a file exists. The command line would not work for you based what you are doing, so I would think that you would need an instantaneous action such as an application that is always running in the background to check if files exist or not.